# In a Spring MVC Hibernate application when using properties file throwing error?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

In Spring MVC Hibernate application , when i am trying to use properties file ,which is under src/java/resources , it is throwing below error :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.lang.String com.mcb.controller.UserController.strDefaultPage; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'mcbPage.name'
```

I am using below code to access property value in my controller class:

```
@Value("${mcbPage.name}") 
private String strDefaultPage;
```

I added bean in my ApplicationContext.xml file for the this property file:

```
<bean id="mcbProperties"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath*:mcb.properties</value>
            <value>file:src/main/resources/mcb.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    <property name="properties" ref="mcbProperties" />
</bean>
```

and my properties file (`mcb.properties`) resides under src/main/resources. `@Autowired` is working fine. but when trying to use propert file it is throwing error while starting the server.
Could somebody help me in solving this ?

Comment: How do you register properties file ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi , now I have added ApplicaitonContext.xml file above. please take a look.

Comment: How are you building your project?  If you're running in eclipse, do you have autobuild enabled?  Also, is src/main/resources set as a source folder in your build path?  It's likely it's not making it into your classes directory.

Comment: @Matt , yes I am using Eclipse and have Maven for build. and I have done all the things which you are saying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**
Use

```
<util:properties id="mcbPage" location="classpath:mcb.properties"/>
```

and then in your Bean

```
private @Value("#{mcbPage['name']}") String strDefaultPage;
```

Comment: you have `name=someValue` entry in properties file ?

Comment: yes finally worked... **Thanks @Jigar**...  and could you tell me why it is not working the way I was trying with (above code <bean id>....)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use @PropertySource("classpath:mysql.properties")

Or

```
1) Add this to your spring config XML .

  <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.
              ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="messages"/>
    </bean>

2) create a property file name calles "messages.properties" and place that in
WEB-INF/Classes folder.

3) Include the following JSTL in jsp.
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

4)Use the properties as follows in JSP.

<fmt:message key="yourPropertyName"/>

5) Make sure you place "messages" in Web-inf/classes
```